# plot $(x,y)$ coordinates to a sphere

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, spherical-geometry

I have a planar mesh of hexagons (or any other shape) that I want to bend into the shape of a half-sphere. For this purpose I want to loop through each vertice in my mesh and find the proper z coordinate. Therefore I need a function that given the $x$ and $y$ coordinates will give me the z coordinate so that the result is a sphere plot.

I have done all the math and from various different starting points I always end up with the function as follows:

$$z = \cos(a\sin y)*\cos(a\sin x)$$

However, the result just does not look like a sphere at all. You can verify this on [livephysics.com](http://www.livephysics.com/tools/mathematical-tools/online-3-d-function-grapher/?livephysicsxmin=-1.5&xmax=1.5&ymin=-1.5&ymax=1.5&zmin=Auto&zmax=Auto&f=cos%28asin%28y%29%29%2acos%28asin%28x%29%29) or see my [result rendering in povray](http://cornergraf.net/for-web/hexagon-net-both.png). (Please note that the rendering does not use orthographic perspective which is why the mesh appears do be wider than the sphere in the top view rendering.)

I need a function that will have a perfect half-sphere, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A sphere's formula in the real space looks like 

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2\;,\;\;a,b,c,r\in\Bbb R$$

If you want a sphere with center in the origin $\,(0,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3\,$ then you *must* choose $\,r>\max\{|x|,|y|\}\,$ , and then take $\,z:=\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}\,$  . Of course, we must assume $\,x,y\,$ are bounded.

Comment: Don gave you a perfect hint but I don't get your question properly. !!?? @cornegraf:

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear. Also I realized that DonAntonio is entirely correct, when I tried his approach before I had been using the + operator instead of -, which of course made it completeley wrong.

DonAntonio please create a proper answer to this question so I can accept it.